# rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange transforming 0 character range into 1 character range

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring

I do not understand why in the following code, the extended range that will be printed is 
"location: 1, length: 1" . Why was the range length extended from 0 to 1?

```
NSString * text = @"abc";
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(1, 0);
NSRange extendedRange  = [text rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:range];
NSLog(@"extended range: location %d, length : %d ",extendedRange.location,extendedRange.length);
```

The doc says that the result of this is:

> The range in the receiver that includes the composed character
>   sequences in range.

with the following discussion

> ```
> This method provides a convenient way to grow a range to include all composed character sequences it overlaps.
> ```

But the text @"abc" does not contain any composed character, which makes me think that the result should be the same range, unmodified, and anyway, I would think that a range of length 0 would not overlap any character.

This looks like a bug to me, but I might have missed something. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bug.

The implementation of `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:` just calls `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:` twice, with the start and end indexes of the range, and returns the combined range.

The documentation does not explicitly state that the characters at the edges of the provided range are never included but I agree that the observed behavior feels wrong.

You should [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:) of `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:` say

> **Return Value**
>
> The range in the receiver that includes the composed character sequences in range.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method provides a convenient way to grow a range to include all composed character sequences it overlaps.

as the `location` is valid it is considering that the range *overlap* the character at this `location`

Comment: The documentation that you are linking to is not the one of rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange. Do you thinks that this is linked anyway ?

Comment: the link works for me, all the ways if you go to the documentation of NSString and then search for `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:` you will find it, you can also did it from the Organizer

Comment: I don't see how a range of length 0 could overlap anything. It still sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: I agree with you, I was just trying to find a *logic explanation*, I think you should file a bug